# Python avoiding recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a  quiz program which has a Main Menu which directs to either a student or teacher log in.  From that log in they are then directed to a student menu or a teacher menu.

My tutor says this is recursive in style and that I must go from the Main Menu to the password checks, back to the Main Menu with a True value and then on to the teacher/student menu.

How do I get a value returned that would do this and how would I code it back into the Main Menu?  Sadly what I have been asked to do is over and above what we were taught on our course hence my needing to

At present the menu code is:

```
 def Main_Menu():
    ##First Menu will splinter off to the Teacher/Student System
        print ("Welcome to the Computer Science Keyword Quiz")
        print ("*" * 30)
        print ("Let's get you to the right place.  Here are your options today:")
        print ("Enter 1 for the Teacher Menu")
        print ("Enter 2 for the Student Menu")
        print ("Enter 3 to Quit")
        while True:
            try:
                choice = int(input ("Enter choice: "))
                if choice == 1:
                    staff_password_check()
                    break
                elif choice == 2:
                    student_user_check()
                    break
                elif choice == 3:
                    break
                else:
                    print ("Invalid choice. Only enter 1 or 2 or 3")

            except ValueError:
                print ("Invalid choice.  Please enter 1 or 2 or 3")

        exit
```

and, as an example the log in check is:

```
def staff_password_check():
    password = "Pa55Word"
##password coded in by owner who will change regularly and inform staff
    attempts = 0
##set so user has limited chances to access the system
    print("Welcome to the Teacher Menu")
    print('Time to check your password')
    while attempts <4 :     
        entered_password = input("Please enter your password: ")  

        attempts = attempts + 1
        if entered_password != password:
           print('Incorrect password entered')
##error printed if user has input incorrect password     

        if entered_password == password:
           print("Welcome Teacher")
           print ("What do you want to do today?")
           Teacher_Menu()
## if correct password is entered the user is taken to the Teacher Menu                      


    if entered_password != password:
       print("You have forgotten your password.  See Mrs Jones")
       anykey = input ("Hit any key to return to the Main Menu: ")
       Main_Menu()
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that your tutor means that instead of calling `Teacher_Menu()` and `Main_Menu()` inside your password check function, you instead `return True` or `return False` and decide what to do with that _inside_ the `Main_Menu` function. Renaming the `staff_password_check` function to something along the lines of `is_authorized_staff` might be a useful way to get the thinking across.

Comment: The idea was that if the Teacher Menu was selected the password was checked (function above) which then gave access to the teacher menu (called from password check). If the password wasn't verified (if a student tried for example) then it returned to the Main Menu to try something else. It hasn't been explained by my tutor why this is incorrect.

Also, if I run the password check and where the password is correct use return True I have no idea how to build that into the Main Menu coding to then take the user to the Teacher Menu. Again, not something taught.

Comment: You're using function calls like `goto`s, using a call of `Main_Menu()` (btw. the common style in Python is to make function names all lowercase) at the end of your subroutines to return to the main function. You should instead rely on the fact that a function will return to its caller after it has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing like this in your `Main_Menu` function

```
    if choice == 1:
         if(staff_password_check()):
             print("Welcome Teacher")
             print ("What do you want to do today?")
             Teacher_Menu()
             break
         else:
             print("You have forgotten your password.  See Mrs Jones")
             anykey = input ("Hit any key to return to the Main Menu: ")
             Main_Menu()
```

and implement the `else` condition for password unmatched case.

Also, modify your `staff_password_check()` function's `while` condition.

```
   if entered_password == password:
       return True
```

and

```
   if entered_password != password:
       return False
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass all variables in Main_Menu parameters

```
def Main_Menu(password_success = None, choice = None):
    if password_success:
        if choice == 1:
            Teacher_Menu()
        else:
            Student_Menu()
    else:
        print ("Welcome to the Computer Science Keyword Quiz")
        print ("*" * 30)
        print ("Let's get you to the right place.  Here are your options today:")
        print ("Enter 1 for the Teacher Menu")
        print ("Enter 2 for the Student Menu")
        print ("Enter 3 to Quit")
        while True:
            try:
                choice = int(input ("Enter choice: "))
                if choice == 1:
                    staff_password_check()
                    break
                elif choice == 2:
                    student_user_check()
                    break
                elif choice == 3:
                    break
                else:
                    print ("Invalid choice. Only enter 1 or 2 or 3")

            except ValueError:
                print ("Invalid choice.  Please enter 1 or 2 or 3")
        exit()

def staff_password_check():
    password = "Pa55Word"
    attempts = 0
    print("Welcome to the Teacher Menu")
    print('Time to check your password')
    while attempts <4 :     
        entered_password = input("Please enter your password: ")  

        attempts = attempts + 1
        if entered_password != password:
            print('Incorrect password entered')  

        if entered_password == password:
            Main_Menu(True, 1)                    


     if entered_password != password:
        print("You have forgotten your password.  See Mrs Jones")
        Main_Menu(False, None)
```

Comment: I've just tried that and the program doesn't run, all I get is >>>